# IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

Tags: apex

I'm not finding a lot of questions and info on this error. I decided that I need to change a list to a map because I want to reuse the map later on and pass a map to another method. I thought it'd be too hard to convert back and forth so why not make it a map and stay with it.

I have a map that I pass to a method and do a query on a detail object to find records where the revenue_pipeline id is in the map. When I try to save I get the error:

> IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

```
// Delete Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule records 
public void deleteSchedule(Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> scheduleToDelete = [SELECT Id,
                                                                 Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id
                                                         FROM Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c
                                                         WHERE Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id In :revPipeline];
    //try{
        delete scheduleToDelete;        
    //} 
    //catch (DmlException e){
    //  System.debug('The following Exception has occured: ' + e.getMessage() + ' at line ' + e.getLineNumber());
    //}
    createRevSchedule(revPipeline);
}
```

What am I doing wrong and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) offers two (iterable) collections: the keys and the values so you need to bind one of those in your query, most likely the keys:

```
WHERE Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id In :revPipeline.keySet()];
```

Comment: It worked thanks! Is there a good to read up more on this I keep getting confused by collections?

Comment: @DanWooding I don't know of a single article: suggest Googling and selectively reading what comes up.

Comment: [Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm)?

Answer (score 3):

Maps don't support the Iterable interface, though both Set and List do. You can use either `:revPipeline.keySet()` or `:revPipeline.values()` instead.